# How it's Check Personal Email Or Business Email in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I was working in Azure Ad. I was Created a Guest user in Azure Azure Ad. It's not gmail or outlook account. in my personal WebEmail of Another website

i give a gmail in as Guest User in AD the user name formated as {email}#EXT#@{myazuredirname}.com
but my webmail given as a guest user in Ad the Username my webmail name and Sourced form as Microsoft Azure Ad(Other Directory)

How to say it's Other Directory. and how to it's find it's business name in Azure.

Any one know reply me.

Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> How to say it's Other Directory.

Because this account create by another Azure Active Directory.

> and how to it's find it's business name in Azure.

`Business name` do you mean user's Email address?

If I understand it correctly, the Email address is `umasankar@menporul.in`.

Also we can use PowerShell to get this account's information:

```
Connect-AzureAD
Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $objectid | fl *
```